# How to use Spring to sign a SOAP message as standalone application

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, x509

I've got the need to be able to write a standalone application/function to be able to sign and verify SOAP based XML messages.

The catch is that this all needs to be done outside of any WebServices framework.  I need to be able to pass my function my SOAP request as a string (XML format), and have my function produce an XML string response.  The signature must sign several header elements (including custom elements) as well as the soap body.

Similarly, I need to be able to validate the signed response by passing it a string of XML and have it return a boolean.

Most of the documentation I've seen does one of two things.

1. Code everything by hand, manually altering XML elements (adding ids, namespaces, etc)
2. Rely on WS frameworks (AXF, JAX-WS, etc) to do the signing

I think that using a WS framework is significant overkill for my simple needs, but at the same time, I don't want to have to manually alter all the elements by hand.

Is there a fair compromise somewhere?  Are there Spring libs that can help me find a middle ground?